# Creating a cylinder with axis centered differently

Tags: matlab, geometry

I know Matlab has a function called cylinder to create the points for a cylinder when number of points along the circumference, and the radius length. What if I don't want a unit cylinder, and also don't want it to center at the default axis (for example along z-axis)? What would be the easiest approach to create such a cylinder? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The previous answer is fine, but you can get matlab to do more of the work for you (because the results of `cylinder` separate `x,y,z` components you need to work a **little** to do the matrix multiplication for the rotation).  To have the center of base of the cylinder at `[x0 y0 z0]`, scaled by `[xf yf xf]` (use `xf=yf` unless you want an elliptic cylinder), use:

```
[x y z] = cylinder;
h=mesh(x*xf+x0,y*yf+y0,z*zf+z0)
```

If you also want to rotate it so it isn't aligned along the z-axis, use `rotate`. For example, to rotate about the `x-axis` by 90 degrees, so it's aligned along the y-axis, use:

```
rotate(h,[1 0 0],90)
```

Comment: One more note. How do I retrieve the points from h once I created the mesh and rotate using the Matlab functions?

Comment: @stanigator: `get(h,'XData')`, `get(h,'YData')` and `get(h,'ZData')`. These are in the same form (default `2 x 21`) as the results of `cylinder`.

Comment: I found a general use function posted on file exchange that is friendlier, and a wrote up an answer for it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32102395/999943  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21951-cone/content//Cone.m

Answer (score 5):

Multiply the points by your favourite combination of a [scaling matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_(geometry)), a [translation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_matrix), and a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Comment: Thanks. That's actually what I somewhat did, although could be done more elegantly using the matrices as mentioned.