# How do I rotate a cylinder in matlab using matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix, rotation, geometry

So, I'm really new to MatLab, and I was trying to make a cylinder using `[X Y Z] = cylinder;`.Then I got these 3 matrices: `X` `Y` and `Z` that generate an actual cylinder if I `mesh` them. Now, what I need help to do is rotate this `[X Y Z]` cylinder 90 degrees clockwise in the `y` axis. I know there is this command called `rotate` but my teacher wants me to use rotation and translation matrices explicitly. How could I create these matrices and multiply them to the cylinder?Is there a better way to make the cylinder? I'm really not used to matlab, if you could explain in a detailed form, I would be very thankful.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the MATLAB rotate function (`edit(which('rotate'))`)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421557/creating-a-cylinder-with-axis-centered-differently The second answer shows exactly what I want to do, but I just can't make it work with `X` `Y` and `Z` . I need to make the cylinder "horizontal"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a rotation matrix for the R^3 which serves as a linear map. There are built in fucntions in MATLAB for that but I guess you are not allowed to use them.

Here is a quick and dirty solution:

```
[X Y Z] = cylinder;
figure;
surf(X,Y,Z);

% set up rotation matrix:
angle_in_degrees = 90;
angle_in_rad = angle_in_degrees* pi/180;
rotationMatrix = [cos(angle_in_rad) 0 sin(angle_in_rad); 0 1 0; -sin(angle_in_rad) 0 cos(angle_in_rad)];

% get points at the two rings and rotate them separately:
positionOld1 = [X(1,:)',Y(1,:)',Z(1,:)'];
positionOld2 = [X(2,:)',Y(2,:)',Z(2,:)'];
positionNew1 = positionOld1*rotationMatrix;
positionNew2 = positionOld2*rotationMatrix;

% reassemble the two sets of points into X Y Z format:
X = [positionNew1(:,1),positionNew2(:,1)];
Y = [positionNew1(:,2),positionNew2(:,2)];
Z = [positionNew1(:,3),positionNew2(:,3)];

figure;
surf(X,Y,Z);
```

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421557/creating-a-cylinder-with-axis-centered-differently take a look at the second answer. That's exactly what I want, but I don't know how to do it, the `[X Y Z]` matrix has two lines and a bunch on columns, if I get the 2D rotation matrix it just doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is that 'cylinder' gives you two sets of points that are located at two rings. One ring at the bottom and one at the top of the cylinder. Between these rings the mesh is spanned. I modified the code above to handle these two sets of points separately.